# How to open a MVC view in another MVC view file?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Bootstrap tabs in a page. And I need every tab to open up a new mvc view.

## CASE:

tab 1: Item Entry

tab 2: Item Type Entry

So, these two are the tabs and when the user clicks tab 1, it will open

> Item/AddItem

"Item" is the Controller, "AddItem" is the Action Name

> Item/AddType

They are different models. Don't know how to link the view page to the DIV element. Any Idea will be great !

Thanks.

---

Using : MVC5, Bootstrap 3

I am using Bootstrap nav tab from here :::

[Bootstrap Nav tab](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=create-dynamic-tabs-via-data-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make AddItem and AddType actions child actions using **Html.Action** helper method and this child action methods render partial views for your tabs.

```
<div class="tab1">@Html.Action("AddItem","Item")</div>

<div class="tab2">@Html.Action("AddType","Item")</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Didn't know about _Html.Action_ method. So it provides a partial view from a View ?

Thanks.

Comment: yes it does and html.partial,html.renderpartial,html.renderaction helpers can supply partial views for main wiew too.